# Javascript / JQuery: browse through an array and put elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

so I made a function that changes the text inside a certain div by elements from an array, this function browses an array of strings, then when it reaches its end, it starts from the beginning

here is the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//This is the array with multiple elements
var array1=["word1" , "word2" , "word3" , "word4" , "word5" , "word6" ];
var i=0;

//This is my function
function f1()
{
    if(i<6)
    {
        $('#change').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).text(array1[i]).fadeIn('slow');
        });
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        i=0;
        $('#change').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).text(array1[i]).fadeIn('slow');
        });
        i++;
    }

}

$("#btn1").click(f1);
});
```

This is the element that should change on each click

```
 <h3 id="change">this is a text</h3>
```

And of course there is the button

```
<button id="btn1">click</button>
```

Now my problem is that, the function shows the elements like this:

word2 --> word3 --> word4 --> word5 --> word6 --> word6 -->word2

It doesn't show the first element, instead it shows the 6th element twice, can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fadeOut` function is asynchronous, so your `i++` happens before the function actually is completed.  What you need to do is move your `i++` to after the animation has finished.

See here:

```
if(i<6)
{
    $('#change').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).text(array1[i]).fadeIn('slow');
        i++; // <-- move here
    });
}
else
{
    i=0;
    $('#change').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).text(array1[i]).fadeIn('slow');
        i++; // <-- move here
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, this worked perfectly, but can you tell me more about this 'asynchronous' thing, thanks!

Ps:you'll be chosen as answer after 8 minutes of time :D

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be based on the [data attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/). The completion of the management of the entire operation is very important in order to avoid to start another cycle before the current one finishes:

```js
//This is the array with multiple elements
var array1=["word1" , "word2" , "word3" , "word4" , "word5" , "word6" ];

$(function () {
  $("#btn1").on('click', function(e) {
    // disable button till the operation is completed
    $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    
    // use data-currentIndex to store the local variable i
    var idx = $('#change').data('currentIndex');
    if (idx === undefined) {
      idx = 0;
    }
    $('#change').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).text(array1[idx]).fadeIn('slow');
      idx = (idx <= (array1.length - 2)) ? (idx + 1) : 0;
      $('#change').data('currentIndex', idx);
      
      // enable button because the operation is now completed
      $("#btn1").removeProp('disabled');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<h3 id="change">this is a text</h3>
<button id="btn1">click</button>
```